# Can I use result of executing lambda expression in assigning property?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm writing a mapper for models, and when I need to assign values to properties of type string from any other types I'd like to call the `ToString()` method in them, get the value, and assign it to the target property.
My code looks something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping lambda expression should looks like:

```
...
var $1 = new Bar();
$1.Id = parameter.Id.ToString();
...
```

Comment: What is parameter?

Comment: parameter is example of Foo class.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. You code that does the thing you want. Where does a lambda fit into this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A working version of how to do this:

```
private Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>> GenerateMapperFunc<TSource, TDestination>()
    {
        var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource)
                                .GetProperties()
                                .Where(x => x.CanRead);
        var targetProperties = typeof(TDestination)
                                .GetProperties()
                                .Where(x => x.CanWrite)
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "source");
        var target = Expression.Variable(typeof(TDestination));
        var allocate = Expression.New(typeof(TDestination));
        var assignTarget = Expression.Assign(target, allocate);

        var statements = new List<Expression>
        {
            assignTarget
        };

        foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
        {

            if (targetProperties.TryGetValue(sourceProperty.Name, out PropertyInfo targetProperty))
            {
                Expression sourcePropertyAssign;

                if (sourceProperty.PropertyType != targetProperty.PropertyType &&
                    sourceProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    var property = Expression.Property(source, sourceProperty);

                    sourcePropertyAssign = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)),
                                                            typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
                }
                else
                {
                    sourcePropertyAssign = Expression.Property(source, sourceProperty);
                }


                var assignProperty = Expression.Assign(
                    Expression.Property(target, targetProperty),
                    sourcePropertyAssign);

                statements.Add(assignProperty);
            }
        }

        statements.Add(target);

        var body = Expression.Block(new[] { target }, statements);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDestination>>(body, source);
    }
```

Comment: Question and answer posted by same user and there is no point in question and answer.

Comment: The two-line version in the question is better.